# How to reduce space between two side by side imageviews in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am stuck for more than an hour on this for know which I believed that was secs task anyways can anyone highlight what is wrong with this -

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ShareButtonsHolder"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonsHolder"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_weight="1">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/script_btn"
android:layout_width="75dip" 
android:layout_height="30dip" 
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:src="@drawable/scriptbig" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/script_btn2"
android:layout_width="75dip" 
android:layout_height="30dip" 
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:src="@drawable/scriptbig2"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If i remove weights than both of them just shift to right side

Image Removed

Comment: There are no buttons in ht layout posted

Comment: post layout snapshot that might clear your idea. @Raghunandan image might use as button

Comment: imageview as buttons @Raghunandan

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot but imageview is not a button and the title is misleading

Comment: guys I edited title sorry

Comment: how do you want this layout to be?

Comment: @hunter how should the imageview's look can you post a snap shot. How much closer do you want them?

Comment: please provide screenshot of your requirement

Comment: You haven't provided `android:orientation` for your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: guys can you check image in edit in the second layout i wanna reduce space

Comment: @hunter check Update code in my answer

Answer (score 1):

**I hope it will be useful.**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/script_btn"
        android:layout_width="75dip" 
        android:layout_height="30dip" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/scriptbig"
        />
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/script_btn2"
        android:layout_width="75dip" 
        android:layout_height="30dip" 
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/scriptbig2"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

## EDIT:

**OR Use this**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/script_btn1"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/scriptbig" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/script_btn2"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/scriptbig2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this !!
I have removed fixed size of width

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/ShareButtonsHolder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonsHolder"
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_weight="1">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/script_btn"
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_height="30dip" 
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:src="@drawable/scriptbig" />
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/script_btn2"
android:layout_width="0dp" 
android:layout_height="30dip" 
android:clickable="true"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:src="@drawable/scriptbig2"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your image will pixelate doing this.

Comment: @Brontok but it is still an answer and might point towards a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

for spacing you can use

> android:layout_marginRight, > android:layout_marginLeft

etc properties and you should define

> android:layout_width="WRAP_CONTENT"

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ShareButtonsHolder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonsHolder"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/script_btn"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/scriptbig" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/script_btn2"
        android:layout_width="75dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/scriptbig2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add that `android:layout_marginRight="20dp"` line to First ImageView

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ShareButtonsHolder"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonsHolder"
**android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"**//remove this two lines
android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
android:layout_weight="1" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/script_btn"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/scriptbig" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/script_btn2"
    android:layout_width="75dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/scriptbig2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try this, I guess you want them like this

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ShareButtonsHolder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonsHolder"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/script_btn"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/script_btn2"
                android:layout_width="75dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem solved. Just use `android:background` in place of `android:src`. If you are using `android:src` then you have the leverage of using `android:scaleType`. This feature gives you options for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of this `ImageView`. If you set `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your `ImageView` then also your problem will be solved.